# Chartjs: Bar width

Tags: canvas, chart.js

I would like to control the bar width of Chartjs bar graph, where it would be possible to visualize something like the following:
[image]

As can be seen there is a horizontal scrollbar that would help move back and forth to say the entire data set. 
I tried to do the same with ChartJs, after looking for a way to control the bar width I didn't find any thing, so I set responsive feature to false and set the width of the canvas to 10000px but I got something like the following:
[image]

It seems after the graph is rendered it get stretched to fit the canvas width, which is not what I wish, for. So, assuming there is a parameter to control the bar width, where can I find it.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the stretch, you need to add `maintainAspectRatio: false` to your options and the bar width is controlled with `barThickness: number`.